# MAC Rename files and move them automatically scripting

Tags: macos, video, script, rename

I want a shell script that runs on a Mac, that when ran, looks for a few things and transfers video files to a specific location on another drive.

So when I put in an SD card, I want the script to autorun, look for files under 300 MB, leave those on the disk, rename the files over 300 MB from "file0001.MOV" to the current date with a number after them.

SO if I have a disk at the time of this post with this shell script on it, insert the disk into the computer with files:

file001.MOV (30 MB)

file002.MOV (500 MB)

file003.MOV (480 MB)

It automatically renames file002.MOV to 20140413-1.MOV and file003.MOV to 20140413-2.MOV and transfers them to D: (or whatever drive I want).

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck? Please note that we expect a little bit of effort shown—people probably won't write a full script for you.

Comment: Well that's just it... I don't know where to start. With the autorun feature I'm talking about, I was wondering if I should use Python, Java, a shell script, Automator, etc... So if I have someone who can guide me in the right direction I am definitely willing to start putting in the work. I am just starting right now, so I have done no work on this.

Comment: I'll be totally honest with everyone, I have no idea what I'm doing. But that didn't stop me from writing a PHP page and converting it to an app.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), it's the tool I'd use for file renaming. There's a built in [date](http://man.cx/date) function so renaming should be easy enough.

The Autorun part can be handled by [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html), which has can start an application when you mount a volume. You'd have to write your script to check that it's the right volume before moving the files which might be a bit more tricky.

Comment: I will start there... awesome, thanks for the input.